# Parameters, Setters and Getters

Tags: java

Is there a way to pass an argument from a class into an array individually (I am not sure how to word it correctly so let me try it with an example).

Suppose I have a class named `Lab` and from this class there is an instance variable named `grade` with a getter and setter. Also, there is an array.

```
public class Lab {
    private double grade;
    private double[] array = new double[10];

    public void setGrade(double grade) { //sets grades for lab reports      
    }

    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;       
    }
```

Now, from a main class called `Teacher` I want to call lab and pass students grades into `setGrade` individually and for each grade passed into the parameter I want those grades to be placed in an array so that in a later class (that I will create) I can retrieve those lab grades.

Scanner input was my first thought but I was just wondering if there is another way to do this using getters, setters, constructors, etc.

Comment: of course you can use setter. but first, consider to use arraylist instead of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to pass a single value each time to an array, you need to keep track of where you can safely add the next value

```
public class Lab {
    private double grade;
    private double[] array = new double[10];
    private int insertPoint = 0;

    public void setGrade(double grade) {
        if (insertPoint < array.length) {
            array[insertPoint] = grade;
            insertPoint++;
        }
    }
```

Now, to get a value, you'll need to know which value you want to get...

```
public double getGrade(int index) {
    double value = 0;
    if (index >= 0 && < insertPoint) {
        value = array[insertPoint];
    }
    return value;       
}
```

Another option might be to pass the index you want to set...

```
    public void setGrade(int index, double grade) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < array.length) {
            array[index] = grade;
        }
    }
```

Or you could use variable arguments...

```
    public void setGrade(double... grade) {
        for (int index = 0; index < grade.length && index < array.length; index++) {
            array[index] = grade;
    }
```

This would allow you to pass a single value or multiple values to the same method...

```
Lab lab = new Lab();
lab.setGrade(1);
lab.setGrade(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
double grades[] = new double[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
lab.setGrabe(grades);
```

Just remember, in above example, each call to `setGrades` replaces the elements in the array (up to the number of elements you pass)

It would be simpler to use some kind of `List` though

Comment: @ManyQuestions No kidding :P.  The OP may not be allowed to use `List` and may be required to use arrays.  There's no context to the question with regards to this, but that would be the (main) reason for using arrays

Comment: If you have free time, I got a question :D

Comment: Not sure I understand the question

Comment: *insert a lame, name related joke

Comment: Thank you very much! I will implement this and try to play around with it and see which method is best for me. Also, once I get my 15 reputation I will make sure to upvote. Thanks again!

Comment: @ManyQuestions Oh I see...:P

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ArrayList. That way you could do the following:

```
private ArrayList<Double> grades = new ArrayList<>();

public void addGrade(double grade){
    grades.add(grade);
}
```

A grade will be added to 'grades' everytime you call addGrade(double grade).

Comment: +1, but Java generics do not support primitive types, so you need to write `ArrayList<Double>` instead of `ArrayList<double>`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Lab` class has to hold multiple grades then it should make it clear as

```
public class Lab {

    private double[] studentGrades;

    public void setStudentGrades(double[] grades) { //sets grades for lab reports      
        studentGrades = grades;
    }

    public double[] getStudentGrades() {
        return studentGrades;       
    }
```

Now, in your `Teacher` class you'll collect the grades in a local array and use the setter to set the values on your `Lab` class object as

```
int numOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();

double[] grades = new double[numOfStudents];
for(i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++) {
     grades[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
}

lab.setStudentGrades(grades);
```

Comment: Thank you! Once I get my 15 reputation I will make sure to upvote.